# JUnit tests to verify DOJO build profile

Tags: javascript, maven, build, junit, dojo

Following is about non-AMD DOJO (below 1.6), but can be applicable to AMD DOJO too:

We have a set of customized Widgets that are extended from DOJO provided Widgets. The customized Widgets are used to render multiple UI components. 
The customized Widgets are included in the UI using a dojo.cache template. Multiple templates, each corresponding to a different theme of UI, exist in the system.

Application build through maven decides, which theme (template) to support in the deployed WAR. A dedicated dojo build profile (one per each theme/environment) is used to compile/optimize all Widgets (in the selected theme) into a single JS file.

dojo.require(path-to-widget) is used to include widgets in the actual code, whereas the associated build profile includes path-to-widget in its list of dependencies.

Above requires developer to include new widget in the build profile in addition to the actual code. A mistake by developer in this regard, is discovered only when the build reaches QA, costing an additional build cycle.

To overcome the costly mistake, we plan to write maven-executable JUnit tests that would validate the dojo.requires in the code and the associate build profile.

Obvious way is to parse the dojo.requires and compare it against the build profile.

My question is - if any better way exists? Whether any tools/framework exists to do such comparison?

Thanks

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Comment: @chris-r I ended up writing my own parser to compare the build profile against the dojo requires. The parser being a JUnit test, runs on every maven build and fails the build if developer misses out adding the newly created widget to the build profile.

Comment: I am open to better suggestions/alternatives on the above. Let me know. Have kept this question open for the same reason.